# PayPal Express error "The totals of the cart item amounts do not match order amounts"

Tags: c#, paypal, paypal-sandbox

There's quite a lot on SO and other forums regarding this error but I've not been able to find an answer that helped.

When I submit the following simplified request without tax amounts it works, but as soon as tax is added the error occurs. Here's the code:

```
pdItem[0] = new PaymentDetailsItemType()
{
    Name = "xyz",
    Amount = new BasicAmountType() { currencyID = CurrencyCodeType.USD, Value = "10.00" },
    Tax = new BasicAmountType() { currencyID = CurrencyCodeType.USD, Value = "2.00" },
    Quantity = "1"
};

PaymentDetailsType pdt = new PaymentDetailsType()
{
    OrderDescription = orderDescription,
    PaymentDetailsItem = pdItem,
    OrderTotal = new BasicAmountType() { currencyID = CurrencyCodeType.USD, Value = "10.00" },
    TaxTotal = new BasicAmountType() { currencyID = CurrencyCodeType.USD, Value = "2.00" }
};
```

I tried all the possible combinations of tax and (net) totals but they all fail. Leave the tax out in pdItem[0] and pdt and it works.

Is it a problem if I leave off the tax and just send the totals including tax? if so, what needs doing for it to work?

Comment: Can you see what is the request (NVP or SOAP) sent to the PayPal server?

Comment: can you print it and paste it here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example you need to include the ItemTotal and make sure you're including the order total with tax and delivery included.

- ItemTotal = 10
- TaxTotal = 2
- OrderTotal = 12

However I would leave tax out to simplify things.

If you work out tax on each item and tax on the total order value seperatley then you are vulnerable to small rounding errors that put the two totals 1 cent away from each other.

You don't need to send the tax information to Paypal, so unless your customers absolutely require it I would leave the seperate tax info out and just send all totals including tax.

We've done this on our site and it simplified things, it stopped all these errors and everyone was happy.

Comment: thanks; now I feel comfortable leaving it off :-)   what you say makes sense for several items, although I still can't quite see why if you have exactly one item with the exact same amounts as in the order (as in the hard-coded example above)

Comment: You're right. After looking at your code more closely I realised that you're not sending and ItemTotal and your OrderTotal does not include the tax. I've updated my answer to include this.